# Why is the city of Sheffield so overrepresented in Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who, real-location

In S01E12 of Nu-Who, in the final round of the deadly quiz game show that parodies [The Weakest Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakest_Link), the [Anne Droid](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Anne_Droid) asks Rose Tyler the question:

> In geography, the Grand Central Ravine is named after which ancient British city?

The answer to which is *Sheffield*.

As a native of Sheffield, this makes me a little more proud than it probably should, and my curiosity lead me to [search Sheffield in the Tardis Wikia](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Sheffield). That link brings up what seems to be a disproportionately high amount of references to a city that hasn't been very popular since the industry of its primary export - steel - collapsed a few decades ago.

In the amount of references to Sheffield that Doctor Who contains, it far outdwarfs [York](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Yorkhttp://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/York), and just about matches [Manchester](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Manchester), which is a far more famous, thriving city, and one that also has better links to the BBC due to being the home of its regional headquarters.

I'm curious as to whether there's a reason for this high level of representation. I'm not expecting an in-universe reason, obviously, but I figured there may be an out-of-universe reason - something like a disproportionate amount of the show's writers or staff hailing from there.

**So is this the case? If it's not, is there a likely reason other than pure coincidence?**

Comment: I believe in the same episode Jack Harkness kind of does a little tribute to *The Full Monty* too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mentions of a particular place in Doctor Who seem to largely follow the size of a city with the exception of London which is massively (dare I say, comically) over-represented.

**London** - Pop 8m - Mentions; **100+**
**Birmingham** - Pop 1.1m - Mentions; **7**
**Leeds** - Pop 750k - Mentions; **4**
**Sheffield** - Pop 550k - Mentions; **5**
**Manchester** - Pop 514k - Mentions; **3**

You're right that Sheffield is *over-mentioned*, but not dramatically so, unlike Glasgow which has a population of just 600k but merits 10 mentions on TV.

Comment: I've ignored the prose novels and concentrated solely on TV mentions and appearances. Since some of the novels are *set* in Northern cities, it sways the figures beyond all recognition.

Comment: "London! What a dump." "London's OK." "No it's not, it's a dump." "You spend an awful lot of time here, considering it's a dump." "I spend an awful lot of time being kidnapped, tortured, shot at, and exterminated. Doesn't mean I like it." *(done from memory because I'm too lazy to Chakoteya it)*

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It's rather frustrating being someone who doesn't live in London. The media in the UK (not to mention musicians, artists, arts funding, etc etc) seem to treat London as "the place to be" and everywhere else as the barbarian lands.

Comment: Where were you getting your sources for the number of mentions? The Tardis Wiki or someplace else?

Comment: Agreed on the treatment of London compared with the rest of the UK, especially the North up to Scotland. It's part of why I so love Eccleston as the 9th Doctor, it's a rare occurrence in such a huge show.

Comment: @Valorum I don't live in London either, and I don't find it frustrating. Of course, I live in another country...

Comment: @Hashim - Tardis wikia plus chakoteya search for the town name.

Comment: “Mentions of a particular place in Doctor Who seem to largely follow the size of a city with the exception of London” — [ahem](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Cardiff), and [ahem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiff). And I think London gets extra mentions because we’re all cooler.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Cardiff and Glasgow seem to be the exceptions. My theory is that the BBC are obliged to mention places that aren't England more.

Comment: @Valorum: could be, and I’m sure the subjugated natives get a real warm glow from each one.

Comment: @valorum but Cardiff (Wales) and Glasgow (Scotland) have never been part of England

Comment: The new Who is produced by [BBC-Wales,](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-wales-25019218) which would account for a more Northerly perspective.

Comment: It's not an exact reversal, but in general the Brits view their North in much the same way us Yanks think of the Southern states.

Comment: @Naib - Actually, the 1542 Act of Union made Wales a part of the Kingdom of England. It was only in the 1700s that it became a separate country again.

Comment: @JoeL. Doctor Who is produced in Cardiff (Wales) which is almost the same latitude as London, so I'm not sure it accounts for a more "northerly perspective". Although it has probably made the series less London-centric (and also spawned the Cardiff-based spin off Torchwood).

Comment: I was surprised to see this question was asked before the start of season 11. Sheffield is obviously even more over-represented now (and I, for one, have no problem with that).